# can you view a view in a table?

Tags: views, database

I loaded a db to see settings of a view but can't access the site so wondering if I can view it via mysql?

OR can you reset the username and pass for admin in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access the command line? If so, try to use Drush (the drupal shell command-line interface) to export the view settings.

If you use Drupal 6, this is possible once you install the [Drush Views](https://drupal.org/project/drush_views) module so it won't help you since you can't access the site.

But if you use Drupal 7, you can use [this patch](https://drupal.org/node/1096648).

Comment: yes can access command ...have drush installed...hmmm ok this looks like might be my answer. will check it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can set the admin account's email in mysql and then have it email you for a password reset.

you should also be able to copy the hashed password value of a known password in to the admin user's password and then login.

Comment: no i've forgotten email unfortunately.